# Python Updating system time

Tags: python, winapi, windows-10, elevated-privileges

I have an application that is time sensitive to the time on a remote server - it needs to be run at a particular instant. Looping and retrieving the server time continuously does not get me as close as i'd like. I am trying to retrieve the server time and update my system's time (Python 3.7, windows 10) in advance so the module can restart as close as possible to the server's time. I have found the SetSysemTime function in win32api.

Here is the two line module i created to test various approaches:

```
import win32api
win32api.SetSystemTime(2020,9,1,21,9,10,10,0)
```

When i run this i get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\pinev\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Projects\Threading Tests\settime.py", line 4, in 
>       win32api.SetSystemTime(2020,9,1,21,9,10,10,0)
>   pywintypes.error: (1314, 'SetSystemTime', 'A required privilege is not held by the client.')

So it seems i have the right solution, but somehow the module's privilege needs to be changed in order for Win10 to process the request. I have researched ways to set the privilege in a Python module and can't seem to find anything that works. If anyone could could provide a solution or a reference it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No expert in this but it seems from the documentation that you need the `SE_SYSTEMTIME_NAME` permission, this may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32776233/se-systemtime-name-privilege-does-not-exists

Comment: How are you going to account for the transmission time?

Comment: I have made numerous timed attempts and gotten a pretty accurate feel for the time it takes to leave my machine and arrive at the server. If i arrive too early, i get rejected; by varying my headstart (how much before the official opening time,  i submit my request), i have a gained good sense of how early i can start and arrive shortly after the start time. I have used this to approximate the transmission time. I have two locations one with 750 Mbps and one with 350 Mbps upload speeds. I have to use different factors in each location.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to elevate privileges to run Python programs, you can launch the program as an administrator.

This is also the simplest and most direct method I think.

Test code:

```
import win32api
import ctypes, sys

def is_admin():
    try:
        return ctypes.windll.shell32.IsUserAnAdmin()
    except:
        return False

if is_admin():
    win32api.SetSystemTime(2020,9,1,21,9,10,10,0)
else:
    # Re-run the program with admin rights
    ctypes.windll.shell32.ShellExecuteW(None, "runas", sys.executable, __file__, None, 1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. I got the elevating to admin privilege message, but still got the error message "A required privilege is not held by the client". Did your solution work in your environment? It finds sys.version_info[0] is >=3, argv is None and returns None.

Comment: @steve  It's strange that when I tested it yesterday, the code worked properly.But I've changed the code and abbreviated some unnecessary code. Now it should work.

Comment: @steve Does this help you ?

Comment: I have had success with your previous version after some more testing. It changes the time, but it still gives me the error message. Not sure about that. Am trying to research the various functions and permissions to see if i can fix it. Here is the error message that persists:

Comment: RESTART: C:\Users\pinev\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\settime6.py =
I am root now.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pinev\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\settime6.py", line 15, in <module>
    win32api.SetSystemTime(2021,9,4,25,4,10,10,0)
pywintypes.error: (1314, 'SetSystemTime', 'A required privilege is not held by the client.')
>>>

Comment: Here is the code:                                                                                               import os
import sys
import win32api
import win32com.shell.shell as shell
from time import sleep
ASADMIN = 'asadmin'

if sys.argv[-1] != ASADMIN:
    script = os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0])
    params = ' '.join([script] + sys.argv[1:] + [ASADMIN])
    shell.ShellExecuteEx(lpVerb='runas', lpFile=sys.executable, lpParameters=params)

print ("I am root now.")
sleep(20)
win32api.SetSystemTime(2021,9,4,25,4,10,10,0)

Comment: @steve You don't seem to try to use my updated code. Please use the latest code I provided for testing. In addition, you can put the posted problem code into the question above.

Comment: @steve Hi, please tell if this is helpful to you.