# Cannot start cmd as admin to perform a net time command to sync computer clock

Tags: c#

I am trying to start cmd to resync the clock of the computer. However, I am getting a System error 1314 "A required privilege is not held by the client". The process to run cmd is started as runas. Looks like this is not enough and cmd is  not starting as admin :(  Any help is welcome. Thanks

```
psi.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";                              
psi.StartInfo.Arguments = @"/c net time \\time server /set /y";
psi.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
psi.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
psi.StartInfo.UserName = "xxxxxx";
psi.StartInfo.Password = password;
psi.StartInfo.Domain = "xxxxxx.ca";
psi.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.hidden;
psi.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
psi.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
psi.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Windows\System32";
psi.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";

            try
            {
                psi.Start();
```

Comment: By using `UseShellExecute = false`, `Verb = "runas"` would be ignored.

Comment: Thanks Steeve, I did not know that. It is working now. However, setting UseSheelExceute to true does not allow me to star ta process as a user. If a remove the user info, the app runs well but the users will get the UAC prompt. I was looking to avoid that. That is why I included the user name and password of an admin user hoping to have the cmd starting with those credentials. Something likes to start cmd as admin. I am not sure now if that is possible

Comment: This might be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32776233/se-systemtime-name-privilege-does-not-exists

Comment: Thanks Klaus, I will take a look :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, at the end I could come to a solution. It is not the most orthodox solution but it has worked well so far. Basically we were looking for a way to help end users working from home to keep their clock sync with the time server. That is why I tried to open cmd with admin credentials from a C# app in order to perform a  net time command. However, this failed as the UAC prompt was triggered asking for admin credentials.  Besides, the solution had to be very easy to use. So, I wrote a .bat to execute the command net time and to delete later an scheduled task. The C# app allow the user to click on a button, and that action will lead the app to schedule a task to perform the .bat mentioned above. The task is scheduled to be performed one minute later, avoiding the 3600 seconds of wait time between sync actions. As I mentioned, the .bat has a line to delete this scheduled task. Having the .bat scheduled to be performed as scheduled task (important to include the RU and RP parameters in the Schtasks command) avoid the UAC prompt

```
DateTime currentTime = DateTime.Now;
DateTime targetTime = currentTime.AddMinutes(1);
......
msiString = @"SCHTASKS /CREATE /SC DAILY /TN task name /TR .bat location path /ST " + targetTime.ToString("HH:mm") + @" /RU admin user /RP admin user password /F"
```